# Login to Community as User not available for some records in Lightning

Tags: community, lightning-experience, login, salesforce-classic

Some users in our organization are trying out Lightning experience, but are finding it hard to Login as Community User (which was available in Manage External User button in Classic). We have reviewed the user's profile (has Manage Users, Manage External Users and Edit on Account) and the profiles are members of the community as well.

Login to Community as User action appears in some Contact records, but only View Customer/Partner User and Disable Customer/Partner user is available on most Contact records. Am I missing something? Can someone guide me on what is needed to keep it consistent - so that one can login as all community users, like how it is available in Classic.

Edit: Also verified, Log in to Community as User button has already been added to the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" section.

Comment: does the missing buttons appear / disappear on specific profiles? take a specific profile for example and see if all users behave the same

Comment: Tried with different users with same community profile. The action is shown for some users, and is missing for others. Tried with different user profiles to login as community user - still the same.

Comment: I have found that in Lighting UI the Login to Community as User is not available at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the "log in to experience as user", the user must have **Edit All** access on **Accounts** in addition to the Manage External Users OR Manage Customer Users